# Biject all points on a plane to the real line

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinity

I understand that the continuum hypothesis implies (since there are only two infinities; discrete and continuous) that the set of points on an n-dimensional plane is equal to (can be bijected to) the points on a 1 dimensional line. Is there a proof of this for a space of arbitrary dimensionality?

Comment: This is true in ZFC for finite $n$ without the continuum hypothesis.  And your understanding of CH is not correct.  You can always create strictly larger sets by taking power sets so it’s not true that there are only two infinities.  As for arbitrary dimensionality, $|\Bbb R^\kappa| \gt |\Bbb R|$ if $\kappa \gt |\Bbb R|$.

Comment: What is a $\kappa$ here? Is it a set? And if so what is an example of it (cardinality more than $|R|$. Also, I'm a noob to this. What does $|R^\kappa|$ mean?

Comment: Sorry about that. I misread your question, which is really about misunderstanding CH, rather than asking about a bijection between the line and the plane.

Comment: Is it true that we don't know of any set with cardinality greater than $|\mathbb R|$? Is there a named hypothesis around it?

Comment: $\cal P\Bbb{(R)}$.

Comment: The set of functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ has cardinality greater than that of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Trebor is there a proof for this? I suppose I should just ask a new question.

Comment: Rohit, those things were discussed before.

Comment: Can you provide links if its not too much trouble?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17914/cardinality-of-the-set-of-all-real-functions-of-real-variable https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93991/what-is-known-about-the-power-set-of-the-real-number-line and probably a lot more.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I am not sure that I understand what the question actually *is*.  Is the question that asked in the title, or the evident confusion regarding the continuum hypothesis?

Comment: $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal.  The notation $\Bbb R^\kappa$ means a sequence of real numbers of length $\kappa$.  It’s usually easier to think of this set as the set of all functions $f:\kappa \to \Bbb R$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The continuum hypothesis is not what you claim. The continuum hypothesis claims the following:

> There is no set with a cardinality that is both strictly greater than $|\mathbb N|$ and strictly smaller than $|\mathbb R|$

---

What you are interested is the claim

> For all $n\in\mathbb N$, the cardinality of $\mathbb R$ is the same as the cardinality of $\mathbb R^n$.

This claim is true, and is independent from the continuum hypothesis.

The sketch of a proof is such:

First of all, we only need to prove that $|\mathbb R|=|\mathbb R^2|$. This is because, if we prove this, then, from the bijection $f^{[1]}:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^2$ which maps $x$ to $(f_1(x), f_2(x))$, we can easily construct a bijection $f^{[2]}:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^3$ as follows:

$$f^{[2]}(x, y) = (x, f_1(x), f_2(x)).$$

This is clearly a bijection, and also, it should be clear that using the same idea, inductivelly, we can construct bijections from $\mathbb R^{n}$ to $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ for any $n$.

To prove that $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^2$ have the same cardinality, what we could do is the following mapping: Take some $x\in\mathbb R$. Write it down in decimal form, i.e. $x=a_{2k}a_{2k-1}\dots a_1.b_1b_2b_3\dots$. Now define the mapping that maps this $x$ to the pair $$(a_{2k}a_{2k-2}\dots a_2.b_2b_4b_6\dots, a_{2k-1}a_{2k-3}\dots a_1.b_1b_3b_5\dots)$$

This mapping is *almost* a bijection. If you just take care of some border cases of infinite nines on the end, you are done.

Comment: All right, thanks for the clarification. How do we prove the claim I'm interested in then? And does it have a name?

Comment: @RohitPandey I updated my answer. I don't know if the claim has a name, but its proof is fairly simple and elementary.

Comment: Why does repeating 9's pose a problem here?

Comment: @Rohit: If you want to read a full proof of this, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183361/examples-of-bijective-map-from-mathbbr3-rightarrow-mathbbr

Answer (score 2):

No, you do *not* understand the Continuum Hypothesis.

What CH is stating is that there is no cardinality *between* $\aleph_0$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$. It does not say anything about *other* cardinalities.

Cantor's theorem tells us that no set is equipotent to its power set, so $$|\Bbb R|<|\mathcal P(\Bbb R)|<|\mathcal P(\mathcal P(\Bbb R))|<\dotsb.$$

And what happens once you've done that through all the natural numbers? Well, then we can take the union and get something even larger. And we can continue.

How far does that go? Well, through the whole backbone of the set theoretic universe. Through the ordinals. There is a reason why the collection of all sets is not a set. It's *really* **really** ***really*** big.

Now. If $V$ is a vector space over $\Bbb R$ then $|V|=\max\{|\Bbb R|,\dim V\}$. Which means that all the finite dimensional, even $\Bbb R[x]$, and even $\Bbb{R^N}$, all have the same cardinality as $\Bbb R$.

But it also means that once we go beyond $|\Bbb R|$, we get strictly larger vector spaces. So $\Bbb{R^R}$ is strictly larger, since there is an obvious injection from $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$ into $\Bbb{R^R}$ ($X$ is mapped to its characteristics function). This tells us that its dimension is also very large.

---

You could argue that we don't care about these sets all that much. That important sets are sets of natural numbers, or real numbers, or sets of specific vector spaces. And all of those are at most the size of $\Bbb R$. And to some extent, you won't be wrong. It's true that most people only care about such sets. (Even if we omit some obvious counterexamples for sake of argument.)

But then it turns out that the set theoretic universe has an effect about *those sets*. For example, are projective sets Lebesgue measurable?

So understanding the set theoretic universe is important. And it turns out that it's a whole universe outside the real numbers.